# How to do time series analysis in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I got a data structure like this: [Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrTVb.png)
It has 365 records for almost everyday of 2017.

How can I do time series analysis on it based on months rather than on days

Answer (score 0):

Please provide next time some code with a dataframe to make it easier to help.

An example you could adapt to your data:

```
df = data.frame("date" = as.Date(c("2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", "2021-10-01")), n=c(123,214,59))

ts = ts(data=df$n, start=min(df$date), frequency=12)
ts
```

And read [r package "ts"](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/ts). Or type ***?ts*** in the console.
For your general question "how to do time series analysis", on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=r%20time%20series%20analysis) you'll find many great videos that'll help you.

Comment: dude, thanks for answering, but for the n column, I got 365 records, how to put all the data into  c( )

Comment: Your data should be in a data.frame (or data.table) with the two columns "date" and "n" and then you can have as much rows as you want. And in your case change "freuency" to 7 or 365 or whatever you need (If i interpret it correctly that its one row per day in year).